# Accessing superclass properties from within a mixin with TypeScript declarations

Tags: typescript, mixins, .d.ts

This is a follow up question to [Using JavaScript Class Mixins with TypeScript Declaration Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58256383/using-javascript-class-mixins-with-typescript-declaration-files)

Given a JavaScript Mixin:

```js
export function Mixin(superclass) {
  return class Consumer extends superclass {
    connectedCallback() {
      super.connectedCallback && super.connectedCallback();
      this.mo = new MutationObserver(console.log)
      this.mo.observe(this)
    }

    classMethod() {
      return true
    }
  }
}
```

And a TypeScript declaration file:

```js
export declare class Consumer extends HTMLElement {
  public classMethod(): boolean
}

declare type Constructor = new (...args: any[]) => HTMLElement;

declare type ReturnConstructor = new (...args: any[]) => HTMLElement & Consumer

export function Mixin<TBase extends Constructor>(superclass: TBase): TBase & ReturnConstructor;
```

I'd expect that the class body of the mixin would pick up on the HTMLElement types from the `superclass`,

however, I receive this error, complaining that the `superclass` does not implement `HTMLElement`

```
error TS2345: Argument of type 'this' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Node'.
  Type 'Consumer' is missing the following properties from type 'Node': baseURI, childNodes, firstChild, isConnected, and 47 more.

  06       this.mo.observe(this);
```

If I add the following JSDoc to the mixin function,

```js
/** @param {typeof HTMLElement} superclass */
export function Mixin(superclass) { /*...*/ }
```

the error disappears, but I get a new one instead, claiming that `Property 'connectedCallback' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.`

How shall I annotate the superclass so that it's types transfer?

Answer (score 1):

Mixin support in TypeScript is not in really good shape yet. Praying they work on this.

But, what you can do based on what you've already done is use the JSDoc

```js
/** @param {PossibleCustomElementConstructor} superclass */
```

where you'd also define

```
interface PossibleCustomElement extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback?(): void
  disconnectedCallback?(): void
  attributeChangedCallback?(attr: string, oldVal: string | null, newVal: string | null): void
  adoptedCallback?(): void
}

interface PossibleCustomElementConstructor {
  new (...args: any[]): PossibleCustomElement
  observedAttributes?: string[]
}
```

Regarding Mixin issues, I've opened [a bunch of them](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Aissue+author%3Atrusktr+mixin), that it seems they are in no hurry to fix.

Comment: From comments on the the typescript web site, they might be waiting for the documentation on the MDN website to be update before supporting this. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/dom-manipulation.html